# Browserify AngularJS Module factory method extend another factory method

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, browserify, factory

I'm currently attempting to implement Browserify over an existing application.

I have a requirement where I have a BaseService that contains a bunch of standard functionality e.g. setting standard headers on requests etc.

In my factories I use loadash to extend the BaseService. For this to work I need to have a reference to BaseService in any factory that tries to extend it. I can't figure out how to pass through this dependency now I have started to use browserify.

I've added sample code below.

**Module declaration:**

```
'use strict';
var angular = require('angular');

module.exports = angular.module('todoApp.services', [require('../secure').name])
    .factory('AuthService', ['$q', 'ConsumerConfig', require('./auth-service')])
    .factory('BaseWebService', ['$http', '$q', 'Encryption', 'nativeCrypto', require('./base-web-service')]);
```

**AuthService:**

```
'use strict';
var _ = require('lodash');

module.exports = function($q, ConsumerConfig) {
    return _.extend({
        config: ConsumerConfig,

        authenticate: function (options) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            this.callService({
                user: options.user,
                url: "/AuthenticateUser",
                type: "GET"
            }).then(function (response) {
                deferred.resolve(response.data.userAuthResponse.responseMessage.Token);
            }, function (error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }, BaseWebService);
};
```

I would ideally like to use DI to inject the dependency but when I try this I keep getting an unknown provider error. Does anyone know how I can get  this working?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking - I solved this by creating a new "Core" module and then having my services module require the core module.

This way everything was loaded in the correct order